# Loading bar covers view

Tags: android, android-layout

Hi there I am trying to use this lib into my app https://github.com/jlmd/AnimatedCircleLoadingView I want it to on top of that layout, can someone please show me ho it is done? I trying adding it but it either covered the whole screen or it would occupy a part of layout completly

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/postBg"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              tools:ignore="ContentDescription">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newStatusHeader"
        style="@style/newStatusHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/postOwnerImage"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/headerInfoContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="@dimen/postsItemMargin">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postOwnerName"
                style="@style/postOwnerName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/postPrivacy"
                style="@style/postPublishDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/publicPrivacy"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#E9E9E9"/>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.github.jlmd.animatedcircleloadingview.AnimatedCircleLoadingView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/circle_loading_view"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            app:mainColor="@color/primaryColor"
            app:secondaryColor="@color/primary_high_light"
            />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newStatusBody"
        style="@style/newStatusBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/circle_loading_view"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagePreview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:visibility="gone"/>



        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/statusEdittext"
            style="@style/statusEditText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="top|left"
            android:hint="@string/urStatus"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:padding="5dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout

            android:id="@+id/placePreviewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/placeValuePreview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Rue Ibn ElArabi, Agadir 80000, Morocco"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_high_light"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/removePlace"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="X"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/urlPreviewLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:visibility="gone"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_insert_link_black"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/urlValuePreview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="https://www.atouchlab.com"
                android:textColor="@color/primary_high_light"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/removeLink"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:padding="4dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:text="X"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#E9E9E9"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newStatusFooter"
        style="@style/newStatusFooter"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addPhoto"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_camera_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addPlace"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_place_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/addLink"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_insert_link_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/changePrivacy"
                style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_privacy_button"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sendStatus"
            style="@style/actionAreaBtns"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_publish_button"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

lib .xml

```
<com.github.jlmd.animatedcircleloadingview.AnimatedCircleLoadingView
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/circle_loading_view"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="250dp"
android:background="@color/background"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
app:mainColor="@color/main_color"
app:secondaryColor="@color/secondary_color"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> it either covered the whole screen or it would occupy a part of layout completly

That's because the main content's root view in your layout is a vertical [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html), which arranges all its children in a single direction, one stacked after the other.

If you want the loading indicator to float on top of all the other layout elements (i.e. in the center of the screen), you'll need something like a [`RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) or [`FrameLayout`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html). This should become the root for all elements that potentially need overlapping.

I'm not going to copy-paste your whole layout, so imagine a simplified version where you have your content and the loading indicator. To position the latter on top of the former using a `FrameLayout` would go like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    < main content root />

    < loading indicator on top of main content />

</FrameLayout>
```

Of course you can wrap the `FrameLayout` on its turn in some other element to allow for screen decorations like a `Toolbar` etc.

This is pretty basic Android stuff and nothing that hasn't been asked before. I suggest to do a little more reading (plenty of resources readily available) and do a search before asking.